# Session timeout could not be changed

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7

I have asp hosting in myasp.net, I tried to change the session timeout 24h but still the server disconnected users after several minutes.
I tried to use c# code like:

Session.Timeout = 3600;

It is how web.config look like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="owin:AutomaticAppStartup" value="false"/>
  </appSettings>

  <system.web>
     <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="80" />
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms timeout="60" />
      </authentication>

    <trace enabled="true" pageOutput="false" requestLimit="40" localOnly="false" />
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime executionTimeout="180" targetFramework="4.5" maxRequestLength="13107200" />
  <customErrors mode="Off" />
  </system.web>
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: what is the timeout set as in IIS..? did you check there to make the setting changes

Answer (score 0):

`Session.Timeout` is not the only thing you should care of. IIS has a recycle timeout usually set to 20 minutes, that causes an Application Pool to release its memory after that time. You should change that too.

As another recommendation, consider using `StateServer` instead of `InProc`, and also setting `debug` to `false` (in production environment of course) to have a more reliable session experience.

Comment: How could I change the IIS settings? Could you give me link to iis management that I could use with my server?

Comment: See this: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.applicationhost/applicationpools/add/recycling